# Update panl in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am working on update panel, when i place radio button list control in update panel and click on radio button it is showing error like :

```
                  Microsoft JScript runtime error:
                  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
                  The message received from the server could not be parsed.
                  Common causes for this error are when the response is modified
                  by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, 
                  or server trace is enabled.
```

My plce the controls like this:

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
               <ContentTemplate>                                        
                   <asp:RadioButtonList ID ="rdbutTrip" runat ="server"  Font-Bold="true"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" GroupName="g" AutoPostBack="True"   onselectedindexchanged="rdbutTrip_SelectedIndexChanged"   >
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Route Wise Report" Value ="R"></asp:ListItem> 
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Transport Wise Report" Value ="T"></asp:ListItem> 
                   </asp:RadioButtonList>
               </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing a ScriptManager control on the page inside  tag.

Comment: I am using master page in master page i have script manager Mr. Rahul

Comment: I would suggest trying Fiddler to see if you are getting the scripts downloaded on the browser side. I tried the code, and removed OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbutTrip_SelectedIndexChanged". Everything works as expected. What have you written in that event?

Comment: in selectedindex event i am trying to disable label control

Comment: Well, I added a new Label and did the same, both inside and outside the update panel... and as expected it works. Try Fiddler as I suggested earlier. Also try, clearing out your IE Cache and see if that helps.

Comment: sorry rahul what is this Fiddler i dont know

Comment: www.fiddlertool.com -> It is an HTTP debugger. Install it, run it and try to check the logs. It isn't very difficult to learn.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error message, Are you using Reponse.Write() on the page or any response filters, HttpModules?

**EDIT:**

Are you trying to generate a report ( i am guessing from the item name Route Wise Report) on RadioButtonList Click event. If yes, then you would be better doing this in a normal postback.

In any case please RadioButtonList Click Event Code.

Comment: ya response.write i am using Mr. Pankay Kumar

Comment: but when i remove that one even though it is giving same error